# Why does ping need setuid permission?

Tags: ping, setuid

I'm looking at a handful of files on my system with setuid permission on my system, by running:

```
sudo find / -perm -4000
```

I noticed that `/bin/ping` shows up on the list.

Can anyone explain why ping requires setuid permission?

Comment: Answered here in 2012 at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51874/ .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In order for `ping` to work it needs to be able to create a *raw* network socket.  This is typically a privileged action.

On a modern Linux system this *can* be granted with "capabilities"

eg on CentOS 7:

```
$ ls -l /bin/ping
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 62088 Nov  7  2016 /bin/ping*

$ getcap /bin/ping
/bin/ping = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+p
```

On Debian 9.1 (Stretch):

```
$ getcap /bin/ping
/bin/ping = cap_net_raw+ep
```

Capabilities are a newer way of performing a more fine-grained form of privilege escalation without granting the whole of "root" that's granted with setuid programs.

Without capabilities then `ping` will need to be setuid root, in order to create the raw network socket.