# Why is sudo required for every sudo executed executable?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, kde

I ran sudo for qtcreator and now I can't do changes to my project_name.user.creator file. It says that it doesn't have permission. Also I ran ping command with sudo and now I can't use it without sudo. Do you know how to remove it?

```
ls -l /bin/ping
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 61240 Nov 10  2016 /bin/ping

ls -ld /usr/share/applications/*creator*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 354 Jul 21  2016 /usr/share/applications/qtcreator.desktop


ping 8.8.8.8
ping: socket: Operation not permitted sudo ping 8.8.8.8

sudo ping 8.8.8.8 [sudo] password for default:
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=1.22 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=1.38 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=1.29 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.229/1.301/1.380/0.074 ms
default@martin-bogdanov:/home$
```

Comment: Please [add to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/443181/edit) the output of running these commands in your terminal window `ls -l /bin/ping` and `ls -ld *creator`.

Comment: The permissions for your `ping` executable are wrong (did you try to `chmod` it?). Run `sudo chmod u+s /bin/ping` ([see here](https://superuser.com/questions/1035977/why-does-ping-require-the-setuid-bit))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

When you execute a command with `sudo` it just means that the user that is executing that command is `root`.

Therefore if the command you are executing creates any files, those files will have the `owner` and `group owner` fileds set to `root`.

Depending on the privileges of the files (also the executables), this may prevent other users to read/write/execute them.

#### Example

This is the output of `ls -l /bin/ping` on my computer:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 61168 Feb 11  2017 /bin/ping
```

I will explain the `-rwxr-xr-x` and `root root` parts.

First character (`-`) represents the type of the file.
`-` Means a regular file.
`d` Means a directory.
and so on.

Next 3 characters (`rwx`) represent the actions that are allowed for the `owner`.

`r` Being able to read a file.
`w` Being able to write to a file.
`x` Being able to execute a file.

Next 3 characters (`r-x`) represent the actions that are allowed for the member of `group owner` group.

`r` Being able to read a file.
`-` **Not** able to write to a file.
`x` Being able to execute a file.

The last 3 characters (`r-x`) represents the actions that are allowed for users that are neither the `owner` nor members of the `group owner` group.

`r` Being able to read a file.
`-` **Not** able to write to a file.
`x` Being able to execute a file.

`root root` Means that the `owner` is the `root` user and the `group owner` is the group `root`.

#### General solution

To change the `owner` and `group owner` to your user account, you can always use

```
sudo chown username:groupname file_name
```

(`groupname` is by default same as `username` if you haven't change it manually.)

This will change the fields `user` to `username` and `group owner` to `groupname` for the file `file_name`.

#### Solution for specific ping problem

As both [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) and [John WH Smith](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/41892/john-wh-smith) pointed out, you also need a `setuid` bit for the `ping` to work properly. Explanations can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1035977/why-does-ping-require-the-setuid-bit) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382771/why-does-ping-need-setuid-permission).

Therefore, this will solve problem with `ping`:

```
sudo chmod u+s /bin/ping
```

Comment: ping 8.8.8.8
ping: socket: Operation not permitted      sudo ping 8.8.8.8
[sudo] password for default: 
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=1.22 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=1.38 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=1.29 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.229/1.301/1.380/0.074 ms
default@martin-bogdanov:/home$

Comment: @martin please put that in your question. It's useful information. You should format it as code by selecting the block and using the `{}` toolbar button.

Comment: @Iskustvo thanks for the permissions explanation. I changed the ownership with chown of the project_name.creator.user file and now I can edit it without running qtcreator as root.

Comment: On some distros, `ping` needs to be setuid root: see for example [Why does ping need setuid permission?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382771/why-does-ping-need-setuid-permission)